# Is it bug in Teechart for Error Series?

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

If std error is negative in case of error series then how to get upper and lower of error series. In other case y+std error and y - std error gives proper answer[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about what sense would a negative error have. Could you please detail it?

Comment: If Bar is negative not error. I wrongly written in question sorry. But still How to calculate Upper and Lower for Error series? have look on image for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want calculate the Upper or Lower for Error Series, I suggest you use two Series One BarError Series and other Error Series, so Error and ErrorBar Series only have ErrorValue, as use in next example of code:

```
    private void InitializeChart()
    {

       tChart1.Aspect.View3D = false;
        double[] GraphData_Mean = new double[3];
        GraphData_Mean[0] = 3;
        GraphData_Mean[1] = 11;
        GraphData_Mean[2] = 34;

        double[] GraphData_Max = new double[3];
        GraphData_Max[0] = 5;
        GraphData_Max[1] = 15;
        GraphData_Max[2] = 23;

        double[] GraphData_Min= new double[3];
        GraphData_Min[0] = 1;
        GraphData_Min[1] = 8;
        GraphData_Min[2] = 17;

        tChart1.Series.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ErrorBar errorBar = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.ErrorBar(tChart1.Chart);
            Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error error1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Error(tChart1.Chart);
            // Error Bar Series
            errorBar.Pen.Color = Color.Black;
            errorBar.ErrorPen.Width = 2;
            errorBar.Brush.Solid = true;
            errorBar.Brush.Color = Color.White;
            errorBar.Marks.Visible = false;
            errorBar.ErrorStyle = ErrorStyles.Top;
            errorBar.HorizAxis = HorizontalAxis.Bottom;
            errorBar.MultiBar = MultiBars.None;
            errorBar.Add(i, GraphData_Mean[i], (GraphData_Max[i] - GraphData_Mean[i]));
            errorBar.BarWidthPercent = 40;
            //  Error Series 
            error1.ErrorPen.Width = 2;
            error1.Brush.Solid = true;
            error1.Color = Color.Black;
            error1.Marks.Visible = false;
            error1.ErrorStyle = ErrorStyles.Bottom;
            error1.HorizAxis = HorizontalAxis.Top;
            error1.MultiBar = MultiBars.None;
            error1.ShowInLegend = false;
            error1.Add(i, GraphData_Mean[i], (GraphData_Mean[i] - GraphData_Min[i]));
            error1.BarWidthPercent = 40;
           }
}
```

When you do implement it,  you only need get the ErrorValue for each Series. If you interested in get the Y value of Series you only need get the value of YValues list for each Series. Can you tell us if previous code help you to achieve as you want? If it doesn't help please let me know and explain step to step as you expect it work.

Thanks,

Best Regards,
Sandra